# Setting ESXi FQDN as the hostname in vCenter using PowerCLI

Tags: powercli, esxi, vcenter

I'm trying to get and set the FQDN as the hostname for ESXi hosts in vCenter.

I have the following command :

```
$esxcli = Get-esxcli -vmhost 192.168.2.21
$getname = $esxcli.system.hostname.get() | select Fullyqualifieddomainname
```

Now when I check the variable value of $`getname` it has a value that I cannot set as the hostname which is :

```
write-host $getname
@{FullyQualifiedDomainName=esxi1.v.lab}
```

I tried using -replace that did not work.

```
$getname =  $getname -replace '[@{FullyqualifiedDomainName=}]',''
write-host $getname
sx1.v.b
```

Is there an alternate way to this.

Currently the ESXi hosts appear with their IP addresses as their display names in vCenter.

[ESXI appear with IP addresses as names in vCenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uKEE.png)

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved.

Since the value returned by `$getname` is in Hash table the key value is retrieved by using the command `$getname.FullyQualifiedDomainName`